# Convert spectral distribution to RGB color

Tags: color, physics, code-request, perception

Presume that I have a spectrum as a function of wavelength (an example being the blackbody spectrum):

[image: blackbody curves]

I want to convert that to a single RGB color to display on-screen, i.e. the "color" of that object as it would appear to the eye. From searching, I can see that there are ways to do this with a [matrix transformation](http://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/specrend/) for a single wavelength, but I was hoping someone already had a solution coded up in *Mathematica* for an arbitrary input spectrum.

Comment: What makes you think that you can input an arbitrary continuous wavelength spectrum and create with a (highly monitor specific) mixture of 3 other wavelength spectra (namely red, green and blue) light which gives your brain the same impression as it would have *seen* the original spectrum?

Comment: @halirutan Within the gamut limitation of the display that is a standard assumption.  It is far from simple however.  Guillochon, even a [basic introduction](http://courses.washington.edu/psy333/lecture_pdfs/chapter7_Color.pdf) to color theory shows that this is not a simple subject.  I am inclined to close this as "requires the services of a professional consultant."  Without an algorithm to implement the vast majority of work on this doesn't specifically relate to *Mathematica*.  I dabbled in this stuff in the past but I never knew enough to derive an algorithm and I've forgotten much.

Comment: @mr.wizard. The question isnt really that complicated. If there aren't any answers by tonight I'll give it a try. Shouldn't take more than 15 minutes.

Comment: @halirutan From reading about it online I agree that it doesn't seem too simple, however it doesn't need to be the *perfect* solution. Mathematica already has some color transformation functions available, so I thought there might be some easy way to relate the matrix transformations to built-in Mathematica functions.

Comment: @Sjoerd I look forward to your answer.  I don't imagine that the computation itself is that involved but the derivation is.  Individuals see color differently, and perceived color depends greatly on contrast, illumination (both spectrum and intensity, e.g. Kruithof curve), field of view, adaptation, etc.  I suppose though these effects are to be ignored and a "standard observer" used however.  Since commenting I learned that version 10 now includes `LABColor` and `XYZColor` which if correctly implemented should simplify conversion to monitor RGB.

Comment: I found an apparently helpful source: http://rip94550.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/color-from-spectrum-to-xyz-and-beyond/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I got my CIE color matching functions from [here](http://www.cvrl.org). These are the CIE 1931 2-deg, XYZ CMFs modified by Judd (1951) and [Vos (1978)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/col.5080030309).

```
{λ, x, y, z} = 
  Import["http://www.cvrl.org/database/data/cmfs/ciexyzjv.csv"]\[Transpose];

ListLinePlot[{{λ, x}\[Transpose], {λ,y}\[Transpose], {λ, z}\[Transpose]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

[image: color matching functions]

Conversion of color temperature to XYZ tristimulus values is done using Planck's radiation law. Note that I make use of vectorization to calculate the integration of the product of black body radiation and the color sensitivity curves over wavelength. I also scale the  output to make Y (more or less the luminance) equal to 1.

```
λ = λ 10^-9; (* wavelength is given in nm *)

XYZ[t_] :=
 Module[{h = 6.62607*10^-34,c = 2.998*10^8, k = 1.38065*10^-23},
  {x, y, z}.((2 h c^2)/((-1 + E^((h c/k)/(t λ))) λ^5)) // #/#[[2]] &
  ]
```

With V10 there are two convenient functions that perform the rest of the transformation for us: `XYZColor` and `ColorConvert` (updated):

```
ColorConvert[XYZColor @@ XYZ[temp], "RGB"]
```

Example:

```
Graphics[
 Table[
  {
   ColorConvert[XYZColor @@ XYZ[i], "RGB"],
   Rectangle[{i, 0}, {i + 50, 5000}]
   },
  {i, 100, 10000, 50}
  ],
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {Automatic, None, None, None},
 FrameLabel -> {"Black body temperature (K)", "", "", ""}
 ]
```

[image: blackbody spectrum]

Note that some clipping can take place in the conversion from XYZ to RGB (sRGB has a rather restricted gamut):

```
ChromaticityPlot[
 {
  "sRGB",
  Table[ColorConvert[XYZColor[XYZ[i]], "RGB"], {i, 100, 40000, 50}],
  Table[XYZColor@XYZ[i], {i, 100, 40000, 50}]
  }
 ]
```

[image: chromaticity plot of blackbody spectrum]

Scaling the XYZ values down somewhat (here with a factor of 2) may provide a solution in some cases:

```
ChromaticityPlot[
 {
  "sRGB",
  Table[ColorConvert[XYZColor[XYZ[i]/2], "RGB"], {i, 100, 40000, 50}],
  Table[XYZColor@XYZ[i], {i, 100, 40000, 50}]
  }
 ]
```

[image: scaled chromaticity plot of blackbody spectrum]

Comment: Nice! I wasn't too far wrong then, just got the normalisation wrong (as I suspected). It seems that the built-in "BlackBodySpectrum"  is not quite right.

Comment: @SimonWoods Color science borders on black magic.

Comment: @Sjoerd Please check the definition for `XYZ`: isn't there a misprint in your code? I cannot reproduce your plots under Win7 x64 with MMa 10.0.0.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I forgot to copy the line of code that gives the downloaded wavelengths the proper size (nm). Added now; thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks, reproduced now.

Comment: Some resources on the internet including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Color_temperature_of_a_black_body.svg) give a different mapping from blackbody radiation to sRGB. [Another resource](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/blackbody/) roughly agrees with wikipedia (and with Mathematica as the other answers demonstrate). They seem to be using similar assumptions to yours to come to a different conclusion. Any hints on how to reconcile your result with theirs?

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries Can you show me how to do it for a given spectrum ? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170498/get-the-color-from-a-spectrum?noredirect=1#comment448181_170498

Comment: @james Replace the second term in the dot product in the XYZ function with a spectrum of your own (it must match the wavelengths in the original lambda array). It looks like the method used in Simon’s answer may be more appropriate for this.

Comment: @ Sjoerd C. de Vries thank you very much. I will try

Answer (score 23):

I thought I'd share my attempt at this, even though it doesn't seem to have worked properly.

The [CIE color matching functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#Color_matching_functions) are tabulated in the `` Image`ColorOperationsDump `` context which is used by [`ChromaticityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChromaticityPlot.html). The context can be loaded by calling `ChromaticityPlot` and then we can interpolate the data to obtain functions:

```
ChromaticityPlot["RGB"];

{x, y, z} = Interpolation[
   Thread[{Image`ColorOperationsDump`$wavelengths, #}]] & /@ 
   Transpose[Image`ColorOperationsDump`tris];

Plot[{x[λ], y[λ], z[λ]}, {λ, 385, 745}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

The X, Y and Z tristimulus values are obtained by integrating the functions over the spectrum, so define the spectrum and the integration:

```
h = 6.63*^-34;  c = 3.0*^8;  k = 1.38*^-23;  nm = 10^-9;

spectrum[T_, λ_] := (λ nm)^-5/(Exp[h c/(λ nm k T)] - 1)

xyzcolor[T_] := NIntegrate[Through[{x, y, z}[λ]] spectrum[T, λ], {λ, 385, 745}]/
  NIntegrate[spectrum[T, λ], {λ, 385, 745}]
```

I've normalised the integral by the total power in the spectrum, but this may not be the correct approach.

[`ColorConvert`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorConvert.html) can be used to convert the XYZ color to RGB. Note that I had to multiply the XYZ color by an arbitrary constant to get the results not to be too dark (this is why I'm not sure about the normalisation).

```
rgbcolor[T_] := ColorConvert[3 xyzcolor[T], "XYZ" -> "RGB"]
```

Here are the colors obtained for temperatures from 500K to 8000K (bottom row) with the results from the built-in "BlackBodySpectrum" above.

```
Graphics[Table[{
   rgbcolor[500 t], Disk[{t, 0}, 0.4],
   ColorData["BlackBodySpectrum"][500 t], Disk[{t, 1}, 0.4]}, {t, 16}],
 Background -> Black]
```

[image]

They are clearly rather different :-(

Comment: Yours might be closer to [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) than to *Mma's*. +1 for the spelunking at least.

Comment: I guess 500K should be somewhat dark.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I enjoy a bit of spelunking, but it does frustrate me sometimes that gems like CIE color matching functions are built in but not made easily available.

Comment: @SimonWoods Can you show me how to do it for a given spectrum ? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170498/get-the-color-from-a-spectrum?noredirect=1#comment448181_170498

Answer (score 8):

Borrowing the analytically-fitted color matching functions `cieX, cieY, cieZ` and `sRGBGamma` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86962), here is a function for generating the colors of the black body spectrum. The conversion being done here assumes a luminance (Y in the XYZ system) of 1:

```
With[{planck = 1/((Exp[1.43877696*^7/(#1 #2)] - 1) #1^5) &,
      tab = Through[{cieX, cieY, cieZ}[Range[380, 780]]]},

     myBlackBodySpectrum[t_?NumericQ] := RGBColor @@ Clip[sRGBGamma[
                {{3.2404542, -1.5371385, -0.49853141},
                 {-0.96926603, 1.8760108, 0.041556017},
                 {0.055643431, -0.20402591, 1.0572252}} . 
                Normalize[tab.planck[Range[380, 780], t], #[[2]] &]], {0, 1}]]
```

(For version 10, see [my other answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115877)).

Compare:

```
GraphicsColumn[{DensityPlot[x, {x, 1000, 10000}, {y, 0, 1500}, 
                            AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> {200, 3},
                            ColorFunction -> "BlackBodySpectrum", 
                            ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
                            PlotLabel -> "BlackBodySpectrum"], 
                DensityPlot[x, {x, 1000, 10000}, {y, 0, 1500}, 
                            AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> {200, 3},
                            ColorFunction -> myBlackBodySpectrum,
                            ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
                            PlotLabel -> "myBlackBodySpectrum"]}]
```

[image: blackbody spectrum comparison]

Comment: I note an issue with this effort: the white point is not as it should be.  My display is calibrated for 6500K so that should look white, i.e. it should match the background of the page.  Instead 5000K looks white.  Would you be willing to take a look at that?  (Edit: I guess my display is irrelevant; the point is that it is calibrated for sRGB which is 6500K, and I think this spectrum is also supposed to be rendered in sRGB, but it does not seem right.)

Comment: I finally figured it out; I should not have used the D50-adapted matrix (which explains why the white point was at 5000 K). I have made the necessary changes here (and in my other answer).

Answer (score 8):

Here, finally, is the direct analog of `newVisibleSpectrum` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73162), which can be used to replace `ColorData["BlackBodySpectrum"]`.

```
ChromaticityPlot; (* pre-load internals *)

newBlackBodySpectrum[t_?NumericQ] :=
   With[{planck = 1/((Exp[1.43877696*^7/(# t)] - 1) #^5) &}, 
        XYZColor @@ ({{1.0478112, 0.022886602, -0.050126976}, (* Bradford D65 -> D50 *)
                      {0.029542398, 0.9904844, -0.017049096},
                      {-0.0092344897, 0.015043617, 0.75213163}} .
                     Normalize[planck[Image`ColorOperationsDump`$wavelengths] .
      Image`ColorOperationsDump`tris, #[[2]] &])]
```

The Bradford chromatic adaptation matrix was needed here since *Mathematica* assumes a D50 whitepoint for `XYZColor[]` (see the docs for `ColorConvert[]`).

Now, 6500 K corresponds to white, as it is supposed to be for D65:

```
ColorConvert[newBlackBodySpectrum[6500], RGBColor]

Graphics[{newBlackBodySpectrum[6500], Disk[]}]
```

[image: practically white]

Compare:

```
GraphicsColumn[{DensityPlot[x, {x, 1000, 10000}, {y, 0, 1500}, 
                            AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> {200, 3},
                            ColorFunction -> "BlackBodySpectrum", 
                            ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
                            PlotLabel -> "BlackBodySpectrum"], 
                DensityPlot[x, {x, 1000, 10000}, {y, 0, 1500}, 
                            AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> {200, 3},
                            ColorFunction -> newBlackBodySpectrum,
                            ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
                            PlotLabel -> "newBlackBodySpectrum"]}]
```

[image: blackbody spectrum comparison]