# How to Write a code to automatically generate the planckian locus in (u,v) space

Tags: plotting, functions, color

in the [CIE XYZ color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space) the three coordinates defining an electromagnetic spectrum are given by

**XT=∫x( λ ) M( λ , T )dλ,                                                       YT=∫y( λ ) M( λ ,T )dλ,                                                                 ZT=∫z( λ) M( λ ,T )d λ,**

where **M(λ,T)** is the [spectral radiant exitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_exitance) of the light being viewed, and **x ( λ ) , y ( λ) ,z ( λ)** are the [color matching functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#Color_matching_functions) of the CIE [standard colormetric observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#CIE_standard_observer) , shown in the diagram below and **λ** is the wavelength.

[image]

the planckian locus is determined by substituting into the above equations the black body spectral radiant exitance, which is given by Planck's law :

[image]

where:

c1 = 2πhc2 is the [first radiation constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#First_and_second_radiation_constants)
c2 = hc/k is the [second radiation constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#First_and_second_radiation_constants)

and

M is the black body spectral radiant exitance (power per unit area per unit wavelength:
watt per square meter per meter (W/m3))

T is the temperature of the black body

h is Planck's constant

c is the speed of light

k is Boltzmann's constant

this will give the planckian locus in CIE XYZ color space. if these coordintaes are XT, YT, ZT, where T is the temperature, then CIE chromaticity coordinates will be

[image]
[image]

A pair of chromaticity coordinates (x,y) can be expressed in MacAdam's chromaticity scale (u,v) as

[image]

A planckian locus can be mapped out in the (u,v) chromaticity space as illustration below

[image]

my question is how to write a code to automatically generate the planckian locus (u,v) space as shown in figure above. The numerical data file for the [color matching functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#Color_matching_functions) **x( λ ) , y( λ) ,z( λ)** can be downloaded from http://comsics.usm.my/tlyoon/teaching/ZCE111_1516SEM2/data/StdObsFuncs.xls as Excel File.

second is Correlated Color Temperature (CCT)
the tristimulus values (X,Y,Z) for a color with a spectral power distribution **S(λ)** are given in terms of **X=∫S( λ )x( λ)d λ ,
Y=∫S( λ)y ( λ)d λ ,
Z=∫S ( λ )z( λ)d λ ,**

where λ is the wavelength of the equivalent monochromatic experimentally
 example from a LED light bulb.

the numerical data from http://comsics.usm.my/tlyoon/teaching/ZCE111_1516SEM2/data/spectral_power_distribution.dat Note that the numerical data for **S(λ)** is expressed in SI unit (In particular the wavelength values in the first column) is in unit of meter).

how do i modify the code to obtain chromaticity coordinates for the spectrum **S(λ)**. Call it **Cs (us , vs )** .

lastly how do i extent the code to do the following: identify a point on the planckian locus **PN (uN , vN )** at which the normal line at the point pass through **Cs (us , vs )**. identify the temperature corresponds to the planckian locus point **PN (uN , vN )** . This temperature is the CCT of the spectrum **S(λ)**.

Output a diagram displaying 
(i) the Planckian curve, 
(ii) the point **Cs (us , vs )**,
(iii) **PN (uN , vN )**,
(iv) the normal line that passes through both **Cs (us , vs )** and
**PN (uN , vN )** , like the sample below.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57389)?

Comment: @J.M. i tried to search already. just the thing that i need. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just to get you started:

```
cpoly = First[Cases[ChromaticityPlot[{}], _GraphicsComplex, ∞]];
xy2uv = LinearFractionalTransform[{DiagonalMatrix[{4, 6}], {0, 0}, {-2, 12}, 3}];

planckLocus[t_?NumericQ] := With[{planck = 1/((Exp[1.43877696*^7/(# t)] - 1) #^5) &}, 
      Normalize[({{1.0478112, 0.022886602, -0.050126976},
                  {0.029542398, 0.9904844, -0.017049096},
                  {-0.0092344897, 0.015043617, 0.75213163}} .
                 Normalize[planck[Image`ColorOperationsDump`$wavelengths] .
                           Image`ColorOperationsDump`tris, #[[2]] &]), Total]]

Show[Graphics[MapAt[xy2uv, cpoly, 1], Frame -> True,
              PlotRange -> {{0.1, 0.45}, {0.25, 0.4}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True],
     ParametricPlot[xy2uv[Most[planckLocus[t]]], {t, 1000, 10000}, PlotStyle -> Black]]
```

[image: Planck locus in CIE 1960 space]

Comment: Note that ``Image`ColorOperationsDump`...`` are imported due to `ChromaticityPlot` being mentioned. If you're trying to just use the `planckLocus` function without the code before its definition in this example, be sure to at least have something like `ChromaticityPlot;` in your code.