# Calculate XYZColor from spectrum and plot in ChromaticityPlot

Tags: plotting, color, data

How can I convert a generic data from an emission spectrum such as this:

```
data = Table[{x, 
    Sum[Exp[-0.1 (x - mid)^2]/mid, {mid, {400, 500, 600}}]}, {x, 380, 
    780}];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

Into the XYZColor coordinates to make a ChromaticityPlot such as this one?

```
ChromaticityPlot["sRGB", "CIE31"]
```

Comment: Some info here: <https://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/specrend/>

Comment: more info here <https://scipython.com/blog/converting-a-spectrum-to-a-colour/>

Comment: I was hoping for a Mathematica based solution.

Comment: The question seems related or might be a duplicate of [Convert spectral distribution to RGB color](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57389/86543)

Comment: Another question that seems to be a duplicate of the question above [Get the color from a spectrum](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170498/86543)

Comment: This wolfram data repository page also obtains color from the spectrum of a light source: https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/Selected-CIE-Colorimetric-Tables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my answer to incorporate substantial comments from @userrandrand.

In equation (1) of https://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/specrend/ it seems to indicate we should convert the wavelengths to their CIE XYZ components, multiply by the intensity, and take the sum of each component.

```
{X, Y, Z} = 
 Total[ResourceFunction[
       "CIEColorMatchingFunctionValues"][#[[1]]]*#[[2]] & /@ data]
(* {0.00998382, 0.00962755, 0.00393729} *)
```

In equation (2) it scales these values by the total to adjust the luminosity.

```
{x, y, z} = {X/(X + Y + Z), Y/(X + Y + Z), Z/(X + Y + Z)}
color=XYZColor[%]
(* {0.423965, 0.408837, 0.167198} *)
```

[image]

Plotting the colors, we can see that `ResourceFunction["CIEColorMatchingFunctionValues"]` correctly places the pure wavelength colors on the outside edge of the "tongue" as shown in  Figure 3 of the article reference above, where as `ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"]`placed them on the triangle.

```
ChromaticityPlot[{XYZColor@
   ResourceFunction["CIEColorMatchingFunctionValues"][400],
  XYZColor@ResourceFunction["CIEColorMatchingFunctionValues"][500],
  XYZColor@ResourceFunction["CIEColorMatchingFunctionValues"][600], 
  color, "sRGB"}, "CIE31", PlotStyle -> {PointSize[.05]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I wrote practically the same code and deleted it because I realized that blending RGB colors does not reproduce the colors expected from adding wavelengths. For example `Blend[{Red, Blue, Green}]` makes `RGBColor[1/3, 1/3, 1/3]` which is gray rather than `RGBColor[1, 1, 1]` which is white and `Blend[{Green, Red}]` does not make a yellow color

Comment: Converting first to XYZColor using  `{Green, Red} // Map[ColorConvert[#, XYZColor] &] // Blend` makes a color that looks more yellow but still not accurate enough that I would trust that to publish a result.

Comment: Finally, I learned that `ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"]` is not accurate. There is a resource function that seemingly gives more accurate colors: [CIEColorMatchingFunctionValues](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CIEColorMatchingFunctionValues/)

Comment: Color space can be specifies in blend.  For example `Blend[{Red, Green}, {.5, .5}, Hue]` gives a nice yellow. I'll try that with the resource function you mentioned.

Comment: Nice I did not know one could specify the color space  with a third argument using `Blend`. As far as I understand the weights do not need to sum to 1. You could also use `Blend[{Red, Green}, {1,1}, Hue]`

Comment: I also found some questions on stack exchange that seem to be duplicates of this one. I added them to the comments below the question.

Comment: `data2 = {XYZColor@
     ResourceFunction[
       "CIEColorMatchingFunctionValues"][#[[1]]], #[[2]]/total} & /@ 
  data;`
`color = Blend[data2[[;; , 1]], data2[[;; , 2]], XYZColor]`
gives a slightly less gray beige where as using Hue in the blend gives a greenish teal.

Comment: I get roughly the same color beige using `Blend` in the ZYZ color space as with multiplying the XYZ coordinates by the intensity and then adding up the X, Y and Z values.

Comment: I found this wolfram data repository page that gives CIE colorimetric tables https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/Selected-CIE-Colorimetric-Tables/

Comment: That page shows how to obtain the color from the spectrum. It normalizes also by the Y coordinate it seems.