# Are there any built-in functions to calculate CIE color matching functions?

Tags: functions, color

I know there are some functions to work with XYZ color space, e.g. `XYZColor`, `ColorConvert` etc.. But I couldn't find any functions to calculate the color matching functions for CIE Standard Observers (2° and 10° ones).

Does Mathematica actually have such built-in functions, or should I continue using my own tabulations of them?

Comment: [Also related.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73161)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data points from 385 nm to 745 nm with 5 nm step are present in Mathematica, but are not directly accessible. [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57457/5208) by [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862) explains how to access them:

```
(* Mention ChromaticityPlot function, otherwise the
   "Image`ColorOperationsDump`..." tables are not loaded *)
ChromaticityPlot;

(* Construct an interpolation function from the tables of
    wavelengths and tristimulus values *)
{x, y, z} = Interpolation[
   Thread[{Image`ColorOperationsDump`$wavelengths, #}]] & /@ 
   Transpose[Image`ColorOperationsDump`tris];

Plot[{x[λ], y[λ], z[λ]}, {λ, 385, 745}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image: Output of the Plot command]

Comment: Just "touching" by evaluating `ChromaticityPlot;` suffices; no need to plot anything.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. thanks, edited.